# ExactTarget CreateSalesforceObject generates two records in salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, ampscript

First-time ExactTarget query from me.

I have a blank email with a single line of code as follows:

```
Set @EventMember=CreateSalesforceObject("EM_Event_Member__c", 3, "EM_Attendee__c",
               "0032000001IICmj", "EM_Event__c", "a0R20000009wruN","EM_Status__c","Invited")
```

This generates a single Salesforce custom object record with three hard-coded values. However 2 identical records are generated in Salesforce. Either when using Send Preview, or Guided Send.

We have tried a variety of lists and data extensions as the subscriber list too.
ET's Chrisoph Cequemel feels this is strange too.

**This did work correctly on Monday - what can have changed to cause this?**
Can anyone advise please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling from two environment? I had this kind of issue earlier. One of my team members has deployed the same client application and so creating two instances.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The only change this week is creating a new app to connect Mobile Push to our MID, but we haven't changed anything connected to Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and contacted support.  They told me the system creates one record for the HTML version of the email and one for the text version of the email.  The choices for resolution are 1) do not sent the email out as a multi-part MIME 2) remove the AMPScript from the text version.

I removed the AMPScript from the text version and am only getting 1 record now.