# claimrow() is claiming two rows for each subscriber when used in a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

This one has me stumped. I have the following AMPScript in an email:

```
%%[

var @em, @couponRow,  @couponCode

if _messagecontext == "PREVIEW" then

    set @couponCode = "XX TEST XX"

else

    set @em = AttributeValue("emailAddr")
    set @subkey = AttributeValue('_subscriberkey')
    set @jobid = AttributeValue('JobID')
    set @dateclaimed = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now(1))

    set @couponRow = ClaimRow('Test_CouponCodes', 'IsClaimed','Email',@em,'Subscriberkey',@subkey,'DateClaimed',@dateclaimed,'JobID',@jobid)

    if empty(@couponRow) then

        RaiseError("No coupons available", false) 

    else
        SET @couponCode = Field(@couponRow, "CouponCode")
    endif

endif

]%%
```

When I do a normal send via Email Studio, this works correctly, that is: one row is claimed for each subscriber.

However, I then used the same email in a journey and when it runs, I now see that **two** rows have been claimed for each subscriber.

I edited the journey and put a 3 Minute Wait period at the start (before the email gets send) to see what happens. Again, **two** rows get claimed, but now I can see a three minute gap between the times that the first and second set were claimed.

So it's as if upon entering the journey, the claimrow() function fires. Then it fires again when the email that contains the claimrow() function gets sent.

No idea what's going on here! Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: do the claimed rows have the same jobid?

Comment: Yes JobID is the same

Answer (score 6):

I can't explain why the 2 rows would be claimed 3 minutes apart, *BUT* I have faced cases where 2 records were created for each subscriber although there was only one Create statement in the code. The root cause was that AMPScript is executed twice for Multipart MIME emails (once for the HTML version, and a second time for the text version)

source : [ExactTarget CreateSalesforceObject generates two records in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47492/exacttarget-createsalesforceobject-generates-two-records-in-salesforce)

What solved it for me was to uncheck the "Multipart MIME" box in the "Advanced Options" tab of the activity. Can you try it and tell us if you get a different behavior ?