# ClaimRow in SSJS does not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs

I have wrapped AMP script function ClaimRow in to the SSJS it works and changes the boolean field to true but when I do lookup rows this change is not visible.. I had issue in the past and that is why I used ClaimRow. Is there any workaround directly in the SSJS activity in automation?

```
var records = Platform.Function.LookupRows(
"dataExtensionsExternalKey",
["processed"],
["False"]
); // does not see the change of previous step`
while (records && records.length) {
  for (var i in records) {

    // do something
    // do something more
    // or just do not do anything at all

    //change record's processed flag to true so they will be skipped in next loop
    //Platform.Function.UpdateRows() does not work WS proxy cannot be used as i am working with shared DEs
    // Platform.Function.ClaimRow() seems not to be existent

     Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(
      '%%[ClaimRow("dataExtensionsExternalKey", "processed","column", "' + records[i].someValue + '" )]%%'
     );

  }
 //query records again
 records = Platform.Function.LookupRows(
    "dataExtensionsExternalKey",
    ["processed"],
    ["False"]
 );
}
```

Comment: Can you update your example to illustrate the fields and values you're claiming and retrieving?  Hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i added entire code.. its not actual code.. i might have some typos but the logic is there

Comment: What's the compelling reason to use SSJS?  AMPscript is natively faster and much simpler.  Also, claiming rows in a loop... not sure that's a good idea, especially with the quirks of that function.

Comment: I second Adam's view on this. If the reason for doing this in SSJS is being able to execute this as part of an automation, Gortonington's SQL based approach, [described here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/336168/36623) is far superior

Comment: i run it in automation i forgot to add. claim row in email worked for me