# ClaimRow Function Does Not Work as expected with Data Extension Entry in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I have an issue with the ClaimRow() function added to an email part of a journey running from a Data Extension entry with 150 contacts. Each contact supposed to receive a unique URL pulled from DE with 150 unique URLs but instead only 3 promo links were assigned to 3 contacts. Does anyone have experiences something like this when using the function for a batch send or DE sends?

Here is the scenario:

The journey has a simple DE entry with 150 contacts imported manually and was activated to run once at specific date/time then sending a simple email.

During the QA before the send, I ran multiple tests of a single sends and the ClaimRow function was working as expecting and clamming the next available row each time I call it.

I've been using this function in another journey which trigger based on SF data not on a batch send (DE entry) and I don't have any issue. I've checked the email tracking data to investigate further and I noticed that few of the contacts that clicked on the CTA received the same URL instead of unique as I was expecting. When I looked into the DE contacting the URLs, I saw that only 3 rows were claimed which looks to me that the very first emails that were send by MC were captured and received unique URL and the rest received duplicates of those same 3 URLs already claimed.

I ran additional test to replicate the journey with 10 test contacts and DE with 10 unique URLs and upon sending this is exactly what happened as I mentioned above. I received 10 emails with only 2 unique URLs assigned and I saw that only 2 rows were claimed from the ClaimRow DE.

I feel that using this function with a batch send caused some sort of error of confusion and only the very first 2-3 contacts received unique promo url.

Here is example of the code I used:

```
        %%[
/* Check for available URLs in Data Extention 'Redeem_URLs' */

var @rows, @rowCount
SET @Rows = LookupRows("Redeem_URLs", "IsClaimed", "False")
SET @RowCount = rowcount(@rows)

IF RowCount(@Rows) >0 
THEN
]%%

 %%[ 

/* Redeem URL and update the DE */   

var @ContactKey, @RedeemURL, @ClaimedDate

set @ContactKey = AttributeValue("ContactID")

if (not empty (@ContactKey)) THEN

set @RedeemURL = Lookup("Redeem_URLs", "RedeemURL", "IsClaimed", "false") /* Retrieve the next available URL */   
set @ClaimedDate = Now(1)

UpdateDE("Redeem_URLs", 1, "RedeemURL", @RedeemURL, "IsClaimed", "true", "ContactKey", @ContactKey, "ClaimedDate", @ClaimedDate) /* Claimed URL will be updated with ContactID and Date */   

]%%

Reedem URL: %%=RedirectTo(@RedeemURL)=%%
```

The AMPscript was added in the beginning of the HTML template and the output inserted into CTA block and also hyperlink (inserted in two places inside the HTML). Here is example of the html codes with the variable:

Email CTA:

```
<tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; padding: 12px;">
                                <a class="mcnButton " title="CLAIM YOUR MEMBERSHIP" href="%%=RedirectTo(@RedeemURL)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-weight: normal;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #222222;">CLAIM YOUR MEMBERSHIP</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Email Text URL:

```
<strong>As part of your membership, we will now fund a <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx" target="_blank">rewilding membership with XXX</a> on your behalf. <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@RedeemURL)=%%" target="_blank"><u>All you have to do is claim your profile</u></a>.</strong><br>
```

Example of the Coupon DE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: where are you calling the claimrow function? I don’t find it in the code above. It seems that you’ve tried to implement it from scratch. Here is an example of how to use it: https://ampscript.guide/claimrow/

Comment: Also, please update your question to include the schema and data sample of your coupon DE.

Comment: @RachidMamai I've updated my question. Thank you for pointing to the AMPscript guide and documentation. As I mentioned the code was working during my testing and also in another journey which trigger from SF data instead of DE. The reason for using the ClaimRow from scratch was that it didn't work in the past with the standard code. I can try using the out of the box code.

Comment: Sure, I've provided an adapted example accordingly in my answer below. Using lookups will not solve your problem anyway because it does not lock the row; hence, the same row can be pulled and sent to multiple contacts...

Comment: Also, please see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/336168/36623 - where Gortonington explains an alternative (SQL based) approach to claimrow function

Comment: @RachidMamai I was using LookUP + UpdateDE function in a different use case where we wanted the contact to be able to claim multiple coupon codes which wasn't possible with the standard ClaimRow function so I found a way around. In this case we actually want unique code for each contact so as you suggested the ClaimRow function can be used. I believe that solved the issue. Do you think that if we do a follow up send to non-clickers the same URL will be assigned to the contacts based on the ContactID when the rows are already claimed? It worked upon testing but I'm not sure if I should risk it?

Comment: @RachidMamai In addition to my last comment I removed the 'RaiseError' part from the AMPscript to prevent the email to be voided if we do a follow up send. As an alternative we can use SQL to match the contacts with their URLs from the RedeemURL DE and the Journey DE then use lookup to pull the correct link but I was wondering if the above will work instead? Thank you again for solving the issue.

Comment: @NikolayNikolov the answer to your first question is yes. Claimrow will return the same url based on the contactid as you said. I assume that a contact can be only once in your source data extension, otherwise you need to handle the case where a contact were assigned multiple coupons differently..

Comment: @RachidMamai Yes, the contacts won't change within the DE so I assume that it's possible to do a follow up. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comment here for more visibility.

It seems that you are trying to implement the function from scratch. Claimrow is a function that already exists.

> Claimrow function returns a row from a data extension and locks the row to
> prevent the information from use in another context until the row
> claimed status changes. If the function finds a row with the correct
> matching set of keys, the function returns those values. If the
> function finds no claimed row, the function sets key values in an
> unclaimed row and returns that row.

Also, I've used it a lot with batch sends without any problem.

Here is an example taken from the ampscript.guide and adapted to your use case:

```
 %%[
if _messagecontext == "PREVIEW" then
    set @redeemURL = "XX TEST XX"
else
    /* include the send context attributes or columns to record here */
    set @ContactKey = AttributeValue("ContactID")
    set @ClaimedDate = Now(1)
    set @urlRow = ClaimRow("Redeem_URLs", "IsClaimed", "ContactKey", @ContactKey, "ClaimedDate", @ClaimedDate)
    if not empty(@urlRow) then
      set @redeemURL = Field(@urlRow , "RedeemURL")
    else
        /* You can do other error handling here */
        /* This aborts the entire send */
        RaiseError("No URLs available", false)
    endif
endif
]%%

redeemURL : %%=v(@redeemURL)=%%
```

**Sources:**

- https://ampscript.guide/claimrow/
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/claimrow.html